# How to use overload `operator==` in a `std::variant` wrapper class to make comparisons between Setting Vs Setting and T vs T?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++17, operator-keyword

I'm trying to write a templated `operator==` for a wrapper class around a `std::variant`. The idea is that the `Setting` class is comparible with other `Setting` objects, as well as the types supported by the variant. I have already solved this problem without templates as its easy to just write out the `operators==`, but its important for me to learn the templating way.

So, this is how I'd like the `Setting` to be used:

```
Setting s1("string");
Setting s2("string");
s1 == s2; // okay, equals true
```

As well as

```
Setting s3("string");
s3 == "string"; // should equal true
std::string s4 = "string";
s3 == s4; // also True
```

Here's what I've got so far, though I'm pretty sure I'm a long way off. The strategy is to template the `operator=` such that if the template argument `T` is a valid variant (`setting_t`) type, then extract the value from the variant as a type `T` and perform the comparison (`T` compares with `T`). Alternatively, when `T` is another `Setting`, we can just directly compare the `setting_` member variables (`Setting` compares with `Setting`).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

using setting_t = std::variant<std::string, int, double>;

/**
 * Utility which is true when
 * type T is in a variant, false otherwise.
 * For instance,
 *  std::string x("a String");
 *  bool truth = isValidVariantType<decltype(x), setting_t>(); // true
 *  
 *  unsigned long x = 4;
 *  bool truth = isValidVariantType<decltype(x), setting_t>(); // false
 */
template<typename T, typename ALL_T>
struct isValidVariantType;

template<typename T, typename... ALL_T>
struct isValidVariantType<T, std::variant<ALL_T...>>
        : public std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, ALL_T>...> {
};

class Setting {
public:
    explicit Setting(setting_t setting)
            : setting_(std::move(setting)) {}

    template <typename T,
            class = typename std::enable_if<isValidVariantType<T, setting_t>::value>::type>
    bool operator==(const T& setting){
        T val = std::get<T>(setting);
        return val == setting;
    }

private:
    setting_t setting_;
};
```

I've spent a good number of hours on this now so I'd appreciate any advice you can give me. Thanks, in advance!

### edit - compiler errors

As requested, here is what the compiler currently generates

When I run SettingTests.SettingVsSetting

```
TEST(SettingTests, SettingVsSetting){
    Setting setting1("a String");
    Setting setting2("a String");
//    bool truth = setting1 == setting2;
}
```

generates the following compiler messages:

```
/home/ciaran/SettingTests/SRC/TemplateTutorialTests.cpp: In member function â€˜virtual void SettingTests_SettingVsSetting_Test::TestBody()â€™:
/home/ciaran/SettingTests/SRC/TemplateTutorialTests.cpp:11:27: error: no match for â€˜operator==â€™ (operand types are â€˜Settingâ€™ and â€˜Settingâ€™)
   11 |     bool truth = setting1 == setting2;
      |                  ~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~
      |                  |           |
      |                  Setting     Setting
In file included from /home/ciaran/SettingTests/SRC/TemplateTutorialTests.cpp:2:
/home/ciaran/SettingTests/SRC/TermplateTutorial.hpp:32:10: note: candidate: â€˜template<class T, class> bool Setting::operator==(const T&)â€™
   32 |     bool operator==(const T& setting){
      |          ^~~~~~~~
/home/ciaran/SettingTests/SRC/TermplateTutorial.hpp:32:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ciaran/SettingTests/SRC/TermplateTutorial.hpp:31:13: error: no type named â€˜typeâ€™ in â€˜struct std::enable_if<false, void>â€™
   31 |             class = typename std::enable_if<isValidVariantType<T, setting_t>::value>::type>
      |             ^~~~~
```

whilst `Setting.SettingVsString`

```
TEST(SettingTests, SettingVsString){
    Setting setting1("a String");
    std::string setting2("a String");
    bool truth = setting1 == setting2;
}
```

generates

```
/home/ciaran/SettingTests/SRC/TermplateTutorial.hpp: In instantiation of â€˜bool Setting::operator==(const T&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; <template-parameter-1-2> = void]â€™:
/home/ciaran/SettingTests/SRC/TemplateTutorialTests.cpp:17:30:   required from here
/home/ciaran/SettingTests/SRC/TermplateTutorial.hpp:33:28: error: no matching function for call to â€˜get<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)â€™
   33 |         T val = std::get<T>(setting);
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/unique_ptr.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/memory:83,
                 from /home/ciaran/SettingTests/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:57,
                 from /home/ciaran/SettingTests/SRC/TemplateTutorialTests.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/utility:223:5: note: candidate: â€˜template<long unsigned int _Int, class _Tp1, class _Tp2> constexpr typename std::tuple_element<_Int, std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2> >::type& std::get(std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>&)â€™
  223 |     get(std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>& __in) noexcept
      |     ^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/utility:223:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/10/utility:228:5: note: candidate: â€˜template<long unsigned int _Int, class _Tp1, class _Tp2> constexpr typename std::tuple_element<_Int, std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2> >::type&& std::get(std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>&&)â€™
  228 |     get(std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>&& __in) noexcept
      |     ^~~

... (it goes on like this for a while)
```

### Edit 3 - alternative `operator==`

```
    template<typename T,
            class = typename std::enable_if<isValidVariantType<T, setting_t>::value>::type>
    bool operator==(const T &setting) {
        if (auto val = std::get_if<T>(&setting_)){
            return *val == setting;
        };
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: problem is `"string"` is not a `std::string`. Is the question specifically about the string issue or do you want to enable `operator=` for any type that can be converted to one of the types in the variant?

Comment: you should add the compiler error message to the question

Comment: The question is about all of the types allowed in the variant type `setting_t` - std::string was just used as an example here.

Comment: When you say `operator=`, do you actually mean `operator==`?  I'm confused.

Comment: Oh, oops. Sorry, that is just a typo.

Comment: your error is also caused by a typo. Actually I'd vote to close, though I was already in the process of writing the answer when i realized that you are not asking for the more compilcated solution

Comment: for the first you just need an ordinary `operator==(const Setting&)` overload. For the secodn the relevant part of the error message is: `error: no matching function for call to get...`

Comment: I very much appreciate you're answer, though I'm yet to find the typo you're talking about -  its probably some nuance I haven't understood, rather than I typo.

Comment: `T val = std::get<T>(setting);` you want to get the value from the variant member, but `setting` is the parameter to the operator. The typo is a missing `_` ;)

Comment: read the implementation of the operator to your rubber duck, or your cat, you `get` the value `val` from `setting` and then compare it to `setting`, does that make sense ?

Comment: fixing the typo the comparison to `std::string` works fine: https://godbolt.org/z/d1eeo4fnq. If you want to compare to string literals as well you could clarify the question a little.

Comment: Ah, that is a terrible typo indeed. And I suspect I need the `std::get_if`. Would you mind un-deleting your answer for a moment while I copy it. I haven't finished parsing it yet.

Comment: the godbolt link is in above comment, the rest of the answer was just fillers

Comment: Got it, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo; you are calling `std::get` on the `setting` argument, instead of `this->setting_`.  Fixing that makes your code compile.

But you can do better.

```
template<class D, class T>
class SettingEqual {
    D const& self() const { return *static_cast<D const*>(this); }
    D & self() { return *static_cast<D*>(this); }
    decltype(auto) setting() { return self().setting_; }
    decltype(auto) setting() const { return self().setting_; }

    friend bool operator==( SettingEqual const& self, T const& t ) {
      if (!std::holds_alternative<T>(self.setting())) return false;
      return std::get<T>(self.setting()) == t;
    }
    friend bool operator==( T const& t, SettingEqual const& self ) {
      return (self==t);
    }
    friend bool operator!=( T const& t, SettingEqual const& self ) {
      return !(self==t);
    }
    friend bool operator!=( SettingEqual const& self, T const& t ) {
      return !(self==t);
    }
};
template<class...Ts>
class SettingT:
    public SettingEqual<SettingT<Ts...>, Ts>...
{
    template<class D, class T>
    friend class SettingEqual;
public:
    explicit SettingT(std::variant<Ts...> setting)
            : setting_(std::move(setting)) {}

private:
    std::variant<Ts...> setting_;
};
using Setting = SettingT<std::string, int, double>;
```

this introduces a `==` and `!=` overload, on both left and right, that participates in overload resolution.

It also checks if the type matches, and says mismatched types are not equal.

The techniques used are "CRTP", where I shove implementation up into a parent class which static cast downcasts, and Koenig or ADL friend operators, which lets me inject non-template `operator==`s into the lookup of `Setting == something` to participate in overload resolution.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/1MPE1Phdd).

Now this isn't bad, but it runs into the problem that it **converts** things to `T`.  So `SettingT<std::string> == "hello"` goes off and creates a `std::string` then puts `"hello"` in it, then compares the `std::string` in the `SettingT` into it.

Really, we want to just dispatch the `"hello"` directly to the `std::string==`, or do something better.

```
template<class T>
struct tag_t {using type=T;};
template<class T>
constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};

template<class T>
struct overload_detect {
  auto operator()(T const&){return tag<T>;};
};
template<class...Ts>
struct overload_detector:overload_detect<Ts>... {
  using overload_detect<Ts>::operator()...;
};
template<class T0, class...Ts>
using best_conversion = typename decltype(overload_detector<Ts...>{}( std::declval<T0 const&>() ))::type;
template<class T, class...Ts>
concept any_conversion = requires (T a) {
    { (std::void_t<best_conversion<T, Ts...>>)(0) };
};

template<class...Ts>
class SettingT
{
public:
    explicit SettingT(std::variant<Ts...> setting)
            : setting_(std::move(setting)) {}
    template<any_conversion<Ts...> U>
    friend bool operator==(SettingT const& self, U const& u) {
        using T = best_conversion<U, Ts...>;
        if (!std::holds_alternative<T>(self.setting_)) return false;
        return std::get<T>(self.setting_) == u;
    }
    template<any_conversion<Ts...> U>
    friend bool operator==(U const& u,SettingT const& self) {
        return self==u;
    }
    template<any_conversion<Ts...> U>
    friend bool operator!=(U const& u,SettingT const& self) {
        return !(self==u);
    }
    template<any_conversion<Ts...> U>
    friend bool operator!=(SettingT const& self, U const& u) {
        return !(self==u);
    }
private:
    std::variant<Ts...> setting_;
};
```

now `best_conversion<X, Ys...>` finds the best conversion among `Ys` for `X` and returns that type, and we dispatch to the `==` without first doing the conversion.

`==` is free to do the conversion, or it can do something more efficient if it chooses.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/7fqj7dsPb).

Comment: I thought getting implicit conversions (string literal->String) to work was going to be impossible, but congrats on solving it!

Comment: @mooing it isn't ideal ideally you'd want to dispatch to the type without converting.

Comment: @MooingDuck bwahaha, got rid of creating the `std::string` when comparing against string literals.